# Bash script to list files periodically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, if-statement

I have a huge set of files, 64,000, and I want to create a Bash script that lists the name of files using

```
ls -1 > file.txt
```

for every 4,000 files and store the resulted file.txt in a separate folder. So, every 4000 files have their names listed in a text files that is stored in a folder. The result is

folder01 contains file.txt that lists files #0-#4000

folder02 contains file.txt that lists files #4001-#8000

folder03 contains file.txt that lists files #8001-#12000

.

.

.

folder16 contains file.txt that lists files #60000-#64000

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
ls -1 | awk '
{
    if (! ((NR-1)%4000)) {
        if (j) close(fnn)
        fn=sprintf("folder%02d",++j)
        system("mkdir "fn)
        fnn=fn"/file.txt"
    }
    print >> fnn
}'
```

**Explanation:**

- NR is the current record number in awk, that is: the current line number.
- NR starts at 1, on the first line, so we subtract 1 such that the `if` statement is true for the first line
- `system` calls an operating system function from within awk
- `print` in itself prints the current line to standard output, we can redirect (and append) the output to the file using `>>`
- All uninitialized variables in awk will have a zero value, so we do not need to say `j=0` in the beginning of the program

Comment: Good one, also it would be useful a little explanation of how your scripts.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for the comment, but I like not to add any explanations unless the OP asks for it..

Comment: Well, I like to think that the answer is not for the OP but for all people that may enter in the site and see it. So the more understanding, the better: more people can learn. But it's my opinion, of course.

Comment: @fedorqui Yes everyone is entitled to their own opinon. Personally, I learn from explanations, but I learn more from trying to understand myself first..

Comment: @Håkon Hægland Awesome solution man. I consider myself n00b with Linux so I agree with fedorqui that an explanation would be very useful. I tried to modify the code to make it extract the files from one directory and then create the new folders and their respective text files in another directory but couldn't work it out. Anyway, great solution and this is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you pretty close;

`ls -1 | split -l 4000 -d - folder`

Run the result of `ls` through `split`, breaking every 4000 lines (`-l 4000`), using numeric suffixes (`-d`), from standard input (`-`) and start the naming of the files with `folder`.

Results in `folder00`, `folder01`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here an exact solution using `awk`:

```
ls -1 | awk '  
 (NR-1) % 4000 == 0 {            
    dir = sprintf("folder%02d", ++nr)
    system("mkdir -p " dir);            
 }                                      
 { print >> dir "/file.txt"} '
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good answers above, but I would also suggest you take a look at the `watch` command.  This will re-run a command every n seconds, so you can, well, *watch* the output.